# HTML CSS: Make Parent Flex equal Width of Children Automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make a Flex Container Parent Container have its Width Equal to Total Width of Children? Right now my width of Parent is taking whole length of screen.
For some reason width 100% is not working. I don't want to manually set the width and height of Parent, but have it automatically configure to whatever can contain child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display: inline-flex` for the parent instead of `display: flex`

```
.parent {
   display: inline-flex;
}
```